# Can I make a BAT file that plays the next track (like multimedia keys)?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, playback, media-keys

I would also like to be able to play the previous track and play/pause.  The problem is my keyboard doesn't have multimedia keys, so I want to setup hotkeys to do the same thing.

Comment: which media player?

Comment: Foobar has /play, /pause, /next, so on so you can run them from a command line. I imagine many other players do too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as far as I know. Are you familiar with [scripting](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm) in [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)?

Answer (score 5):

As described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190618134817/https://synthiam.com/Community/Questions/How-To-Control-Windows-Media-Player-1768), you can create a powershell script which gets called by a batch file:

`script.ps1`:

```
$wshShell = new-object -com wscript.shell
$wshShell.SendKeys([char]176)
```

`next_track.bat`:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\path\to\your\script.ps1"
```

There's also a list of other keys:

> Mute/Unmute: 173
>   Volume Down: 174
>   Volume Up: 175
>   Next Track: 176
>   Previous Track: 177
>   Stop Media: 178
>   Play/Pause: 179

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use Autohotkey as this allows you to map keyboard shortcuts for most programs.

http://www.hacksar.com/blog/2009/03/09/how-to-control-itunes-from-anywhere-autohotkey/

look here